# About integration by parts

Tags: integration

How to write the following integral as $\int_{0}^{t}u(x,s)...ds$ by using integration by parts?
$$\int^{t}_0u_{xx}(x,s)(t-s)^{-\beta}ds$$
where it is continous on
$(x,s,t) \in [x_0,x_1] \times [0,t] \times [t_0,t_1]$.

If it is not possible, is there another method excluding integration by parts?

If the question were $$\int^{t}_0u_{xx}(x,s)(x-s)^{-\beta}dx$$

we could simply apply integration by parts.

Comment: For the second one, you don't need by parts :)
$$
\int^{t}_0u_{xx}(x,s)(t-s)^{-\beta}dx = (t-s)^{-\beta} \int^{t}_0u_{xx}(x,s)dx
$$

Comment: Do the hypotheses of the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) apply to $u(x,s)(t-s)^\beta$, $u_x(x,s)(t-s)^\beta$, and $u_{xx}(x,s)(t-s)^\beta$?  There's not enough information here to conclude continuity on $(x,s,t) \in [x_0,x_1] \times [0,t] \times [t_0,t_1]$ for some choice of $x_0, x_1, t_0, t_1$ and $t \in [t_0, t_1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts is based on the product rule, if the integration is with respect of a parameter which is not differentiated, then it does not apply.

However, consider the following indefinite integral
$$\int (t-s)^{-\beta}ds=-\frac{(t-s)^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta}.$$
This means we can integrate by parts with respect to $s$
$$\int u_{xx}(x, s)(t-s)^{-\beta} ds
=-u_{xx}(x, s)\frac{(t-s)^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta}\Bigg|_{s=0}^{s=t}
+\int u_{xxs}(x, s)\frac{(t-s)^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta} ds.$$